# WebView loads url more than a time in android

Tags: android

webview in android loads more than once while loading the url.
Below is the code.

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {

                if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
                    String[] spliturl = url.split("http://someurl/");
                    String googleurl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=";
                    System.out.println("Google Url"+googleurl);
                    System.out.println("spliturl"+spliturl[1]);
                     view.loadUrl(googleurl+spliturl[1]);
                }
                else
                     view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

I am splitting the url as it contains more than one url to be passed on google document viewer for rendering the pdf document. 
First time the url is correctly split and the url is concatenated to open in google docs but the webview executes again there by giving an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at spliturl[1].
Could anybody let me know why is this executing again.
thanks.

Comment: may be it will be more sample if you open the pdf directly in the navigator:
String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+documentUrl;   
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check if an array has a size more than the index requested:

```
if (url.contains(".pdf") && url.split("http://someurl/").size()>2){
// your code
}
```

Don't know why it gets called though - probably multiple redirections.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it gets called multiple times, but the solution is to handle it in onPageStarted rather than in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
    boolean calledOnce=false;

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    if (url.contains(".pdf") && !calledOnce) {
            String[] spliturl = url.split("http://someurl/");
            String googleurl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=";
            System.out.println("Google Url"+googleurl);
            System.out.println("spliturl"+spliturl[1]);
            url = googleurl+spliturl[1];
            calledOnce = true;
        }       
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}
```